# Why does JavaScript setTimeout lag when in another tab?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using setTimeout to run a JavaScript program that will use AJAX to fetch external data and update the content of the page once every 1000 milliseconds, or one second.

This works perfectly fine when the tab that my web page is on is in the forefront. However, if the page is running in a browser window with multiple tabs, and the user is not currently in that tab, then the setTimeout will begin to lag (in one minute, rather than updating 60 times, it only updates around 30).

However, if the web page is in the forefront of a browser window that is in the background, then setTimeout will continue to run at the correct speed.

Can someone please explain why this is happening, and any ways to resolve this?

Comment: This might supply the answer for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers squelch timer frequencies when tabs aren't active to save battery life for users.

Comment: Is there any way to get by this? I was looking at a JavaScript timer on another website (progamingleague.com), and even when I switched tabs their timer continued to run accurately. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: It's not under programmatic control. It's a thing that modern browsers do. The best you can do is check the clock and see how your timer is actually running, vs. how it *thinks* it's running.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "check the clock and see how your timer is actually running, vs. how it thinks it's running." Is it something to do with recording the system time at the beginning, then counting the number of intervals at 1000ms each and comparing that to the actual system time?

Comment: Basically, in your timeout/interval handler, you keep track of actual wall clock time via `Date.now()` or whatever, and see what your actual frequency is. That way if you're doing incremental animation or something, you can adjust to what the browser is doing.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for the suggestion.